# how to Find a substring in a bash shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable like below.

```
variable = This script is not found

if [[ "$variable" = ~ "not found" ]];
then
echo "Not Found"
else
echo "Its there"
if
```

while executing im getting below err,

```
line 4: syntax error in conditional expression
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near `found"'
./test.sh: line 4: `if [[ "$variable" = ~ "not found" ]]; '
```

could anyone point me, What im missing here?

Comment: There should not be a space between `=` and `~`.  Write as `=~`

Comment: Have tried that before. But got other err line 4: conditional binary operator expected ./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near `=~' ./test.sh: line 4: `if [[ "$variable" =~ "not found" ]]; '

Comment: what happens if you change your assigment at the top to `variable="This script is not found"` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
LIST="some string with a substring you want to match"
SOURCE="substring"

if echo "$LIST" | grep -q "$SOURCE"; then
    echo "matched";
else
    echo "no match";
fi
```

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 11):

Compare this with your version at the indicated points:

```
variable="This script is not found"  # <--

if [[ "$variable" =~ "not found" ]]  # <--
then
    echo "Not Found"
else
    echo "Its there"
fi  # <--
```

You can't put spaces around = in an assignment, and you need to quote a string literal that has spaces. You don't need a trailing ; if you're going to put then on its own line. And an if-then ends with "fi" not "if".

Answer (score 2):

here is a correct construction of your if statement

```
if [[ "$variable" =~ "not found" ]]; then
      echo "Not Found";
else
      echo "Its there";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
line="There\'s a substring to be found!"

if [[ "$line" =~ *"substring"* ]]; then
    echo "Not Found";
else
    echo "Found!"
fi
```

Output:

```
Found!
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried below codes which always return same result either in true or false

```
if [[ "$variable" =~ "not found" ]]; then
      echo "Not Found";
else
      echo "Its there";
fi
```