# Bash: repeating loop issue (novice user)

Tags: bash

Good afternoon,
I'm trying to figure out why my variable loop is only using the last line in my do loop to write data my ISLAND loop is finding city names and assigning a static variable (ISLAND-X-XO)

```
IFS=$'\n'
OUTPUTDIR='/home/IMPACT_COUNT'
for CSR in `ls -1 configs/ | egrep 'router{1-5]'`
do

ISLAND=$(echo $CSR | grep -q "tampa" && echo ISLAND-TAM-MCR-XO) <- does not write
ISLAND=$(echo $CSR | egrep -q "washington-dc|ashburn" && echo ISLAND-WDC-XO) <- writes
COUNT=$(grep "up             up"  /otherconfigs/$CSR | wc -l)
echo $CSR $COUNT >> $OUTPUTDIR/$ISLAND
done
```

Each one of the "ISLAND" lookups works individually, just not stacked.

Tried [if then] options
Expecting multiple lookups in the loop to write to the DIR

Comment: To increase the code quality: add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Do what @Cyrus suggested and do not do what was suggested in [the 1 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75738936/1745001) you have so far - shellcheck would also tell you some (but not all) of the issues with that. If you [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with your code after fixing the issues shellcheck tells you about and concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do what you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here:

```
ISLAND=$(echo $CSR | grep -q "tampa" && echo ISLAND-TAM-MCR-XO) <- does not write
ISLAND=$(echo $CSR | egrep -q "washington-dc|ashburn" && echo ISLAND-WDC-XO) <- writes
```

You are overwriting the variable in the second line. Try something like this:

```
if echo $CSR | grep -q "tampa"; then
    ISLAND=ISLAND-TAM-MCR-XO
elif echo $CSR | egrep -q "washington-dc|ashburn"; then
    ISLAND=ISLAND-WDC-XO
fi
```

Comment: `bash` has everything built in to find a string in a variable. I suggest to use [this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120074/3776858).